# Benchmarking 700 Netbook Computers running Windows XP - Netboot Ubunutu

Tags: boot, networking, system-installation

I have several hundred netbook computers that I need to benchmark (run a series of diagnostic tests on the battery, hard drive, SD card, etc).

All of these computers run Windows XP, and are never connected to the internet. Previously when these computers were benchmarked, multiple applications were installed individually (off a flash drive) on each machine and then uninstalled at the end.

I'd like to streamline this process, and PXE boot a copy of Ubuntu with the pre-installed benchmarking tools. The idea would be to plug in an Ethernet cable, boot from the network, and run a number of commands to test the hardware. Then, when it's finished, reboot and disconnect the cable to boot into Windows XP (as if nothing ever happened).

I have a copy of Windows Server 2012 R2 setup with with a tool (the name escapes me) where I have the option to boot WDS, from the internal hard drive, or any additional linux images. This has been correctly configured with DHCP, to the point where I can network boot from a netbook and reach this screen.

Where I've become stuck though, is preparing and booting a copy of Ubuntu. Most of the tutorials I've seen either relate to setting up a network install version of Ubuntu (to install to the local disk over the network), or having a complete linux stack (and installing TFTP on Ubuntu).

Is anyone able to point me in the direction of a tutorial that lets me (a) setup a copy of Ubuntu, preinstalling my required diagnostic tools and then (b) somehow getting this onto my server to be able to boot from?